# High Kurtosis with normal Distribution

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, mathematical-economics, finance, financial-economics

I need help. Here is my problem, I am testing normal distribution on covid, 2008 crisis, and beetween these. So I have 3 timezone and 7 indexes. When I use SPSS to test the normal distribution with skewness kurtosis shapiro and kolmogorv, the kolmogorov and Shapiro results showing me I have normal distribution but, I have high Kurtosis levels which is not normal. I don't understand how is it possible. Here is a picture about this.
[image]

Comment: Hi @user41110. You should reject the null (i.e. reject normality) with your p-values.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explain please?

Comment: Hi @user41110. Sorry for any ambiguity. You should reject your null hypothesis with a p-value less that 0.05. In particular, you should reject the Shapiro null  that 'the data is distributed normally.' Therefore, since .001 < 0.05, you should reject your null; and thus you should reject normality distributed data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why are the kurtosis values are this high?

Comment: Lots of outliers would make sense. But you should plot your data to get some good visuals of what's going on.

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot!